# Fundamental theorem of Finitely generated abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

According to this theorem, $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$, but the order of the elements are not preserved.

> Does isomorphism preserve order of the group alone?

Comment: That's not what the Theorem says....those two groups aren't isomorphic (for the reason you point out).

Comment: The Theorem you cite just says that finite abelian groups are direct products of cyclic groups of prime power order and that the group is determined (up to isomorphism) by the number of factors and their orders.  The first group you mention has a single cyclic factor (of order $4$) and the second group has two factors (both of order $2$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This post is an edit of my original post, which incorrectly stated the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups.*

$\mathbb{Z}_4$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

The theorem says that if $G$ is an abelian group of order $m$ then there exist primes $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n$ and exponents $e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_n$ with

$$
m = p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_n^{e_n}
$$

Such
$$G = \mathbb{Z}_{p_1^{e_1}} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p_2^{e_2}} \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_{p_n^{e_n}}$$

$G$ is decomposed into groups of prime-power order, not simply prime order. So $\mathbb{Z}_4 \not\cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ but $\mathbb{Z}_6 \cong \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ since $6 = 3\cdot2$. There are two abelian groups of order $12$, $G_1 \cong \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ and $G_2 = \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: How about Z12 decomposition?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_{12} = \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$. Can you see why?

Comment: Yeah i do... Thank you